# Gatsby dynamic route with multiple parameters

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to get gatsby to work with dynamic routes with multiple url parameters.
I want to be able to navigate to:

.../items/124/MyItemsTitle

In my gatsby-node.js i have the following code:

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
    // only on the client.
    if (page.path.match(/^\/user/)) {
        page.matchPath = "/user/*";
        // Update the page.
        createPage(page);
    }

    if (page.path.match(/^\/items\/([0-9]+)\/\w+$/)) {
        page.matchPath = "/items/:itemId/:itemTitle";
        // Update the page.
        createPage(page);
    }
};
```

The component for the router is as follows:

items.js

```
   <Router>
            <ItemDetail path="/items/:itemId/:itemTitle" />
        </Router>
```

But it just renders out to the 404

I have tried every type of regex available
read through the docs multiple times, but always end up with only one variable in the url.
then it works.
The soon as I use multiple parameters, it breaks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue:

Adding this to gatsby-node.js was enough

```
if (page.path.match(/^\/items/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/items/*";
    // Update the page.
    createPage(page);
}
```

And the rest of the path is handled by the router.
So the more parameters you want, just add them to the path of your component in the router.

```
 <Router>
        <Items path="/items/:itemId" />
        <ItemDetail path="/items/:itemId/:itemTitle" />
 </Router>
```

And this worked for me.